# View with Full Outer Join to produce non-null column for use with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, join

I'm working to create a view that uses a full outer join and then a left outer join to join to it.  The view produces the results I want, but we're using EF6 Database first to pull in the DB object into a .net MVC application.  With that we have to have at least one column in the view be non-null unique to allow ef to create the inferred primary key.  I tried adding it afterwards but couldn't get around it because the view in SQL with the full outer join has to allow nulls.

I also tried union and union all but that creates duplicates.  I want the non-null unique values.

For example.  Let's say TableA, TableB, and TableC all have the same primary key.  All tables have different columns (which is why union all produces duplicates).  I want the merged results where merged.

```
Select 
 c.guid
 ,a.something
 ,b.something
 ,c.something
 ,etc
FROM (TableA as a Full Outer Join TableB as b on a.guid = b.guid) LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TableC as c on c.guid = a.guid OR c.guid = b.guid
```

I've also tried a right outer join with TableC first but that gives the same results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, it should be like this:

```
...
left join dbo.TableC c on c.guid = isnull(a.guid, b.guid)
```

On the other hand, since C is actually a supertype for A and B, the join order should be the opposite:

```
select c.guid, ...
from dbo.TableC c
  left join dbo.TableA a on a.guid = c.guid
  left join dbo.TableB b on b.guid = c.guid
where isnull(a.guid, b.guid) is not null
...
```

You should have mentioned this circumstance from the start.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
Select Coalesce(a.guid, b.guid, c.guid) As guid,
       (the rest of your query here)
```

Comment: No luck.  Thank you for the answer though.  It produces the same results, where there are no nulls and the guid column is unique, however, the View lists the column as nullable.  Maybe a better question was how to a force the column to be non-nullable using a full outer join?

Comment: If this is a view, try creating the view with the code I show and then put an index on the view that is unique and non-nullable?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid an index and bringing that view onto disk. I'm hoping there is an alternative?

Comment: I should also mention that Table C has all GUIDs while TableA and TableB have a subset of TableC

Comment: Ugh.  I think I answered my own question.  I moved TableC to the front and did an inner join on the full outer join keep the ON OR the same and it looks like it worked.  We'll see if there is any speed issues...  might have to go indexed

Answer (score 0):

If it's a generalization model, wouldn't this work?  Since c always exists, when a is-a c OR b is-a c.

```
select 
    c.guid, ISNULL(a.guid, 'N/A'), ISNULL(b.guid, 'N/A'), *
FROM
    TableC c
    INNER JOIN TableA a ON c.guid = a.guid
    INNER JOIN TableB b ON c.guid = b.guid
```